# rxjava2 - how to block until a call back completes and then do a retrofit call?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

IM having a hard issue using BlockingObservable. I have a situation where i need to call back completed and after it completes then i can do a retrofit API call to get data.  To be specific, i need to initialize a payment gateway sdk first, and then after it successfullly initializes i will make a retrofit call.  Here is what i have so far:

```
  Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<PaymentStrategy>() {

                    @Override
                    public PaymentStrategy call() throws Exception {
                        return gatewayFactory.getPaymentStrategy("US");
                    }}).flatMap(new Function<PaymentStrategy, ObservableSource<PaymentStrategy>>() {
                    @Override
                    public ObservableSource<PaymentStrategy> apply(@NonNull final PaymentStrategy paymentStrategy) throws Exception {
                        return Observable.fromCallable(new Callable<PaymentStrategy>() {
                            @Override
                            public PaymentStrategy call() throws Exception {


        /*here is important. i want it to block until init actually
     gets a call back. when it does the subscriber will call
 onComplete and the observable should move forward at that point*/


                                paymentStrategy.init(paymentInitSubscriber);
                                return paymentStrategy;
                            }
                        });
                    }}).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(paymentInitSubscriber);
```

it seems rxjava2 does not have a toBlocking() call but i did find a toBlockingFirst() etc and BlockingObservable classes. but im not sure how to accomplish the task still.  So to be clear, when i call paymentStrategy.init() i need the observable to just block until the the subscribers onComplete or onNext is called. i am passing the subscriber as a parameter so that the callback knows to invoke it when it completes. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

i found that i was better to use a Flowable and supply it with an emitter. then i can emit events like onNext and onComplete etc.

```
final PaymentStrategy paymentStrategy = gatewayFactory.getPaymentStrategy("US");

            FlowableOnSubscribe flowableOnSubscribe = new FlowableOnSubscribe() {
                @Override
                public void subscribe(FlowableEmitter e) throws Exception {
                    FlowableEmitter initdownFlowableEmitter = e;
                    paymentStrategy.init(e);
    /* above i pass in the emitter and i can call onNext when the call back i want completes. this pushes the stream forward to the next one below of the retrofit call */
                }
            };

            final Flowable flowable = Flowable.create(flowableOnSubscribe, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);
            return flowable.flatMap(new Function() {
                @Override
                public Object apply(@NonNull Object o) throws Exception {
                    PaymentApi service = mRetrofit.create(PaymentApi.class);
                    return service.getCards();
                }
            }).toObservable();
```

and dont forget in the retrofit class to use a Flowable instead of an observable.

it seems fromAsync has been renamed to Flowable.create as per the github notes [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/What's-different-in-2.0):

> Practically, the 1.x fromEmitter (formerly fromAsync) has been renamed to Flowable.create.